# Extract href attribute value of <a> if it contains specific keyword

Tags: javascript, regex, string, substring, text-extraction

How is it possible to get the the full link from a string like this:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/setprefdomain?prefdom=DE&amp;prev=https://www.google.de/&amp;sig=K_DtcF1dnV7Xn6g9Ir_3SUs6a6TiA%3D">
```

I want to isolate the string starting after 'href="' and ending with 'A%3D', but only if this string contains the string `domain`.

I don't really know, how to check, if the string 'domain' is included.

My regex so far is: `/(?<=href=")(.*)(?=")/gi`

Answer (score 1):

I love regex, but I prefer not to parse valid html with it as a matter of stability.

Use a legitimate parsing technique to isolate the `href` attribute.  This will ensure that you will never accidentally match `data-href` or any other attributes that share the consecutive letters `href`.  This also frees the burden of needing to match the possibility of single quotes or double quotes.

After the href attribute is isolated, use `includes()` or `indexOf()` to check if `domain` is anywhere in the string value.  If you need to tighten up the accuracy of matching `domain`, you might now entertain using regex with word boundaries or other checks on surrounding substrings (such as checking if `domain` occurs before the first `?`).

```js
const str = '<a href="https://www.google.com/setprefdomain?prefdom=DE&amp;prev=https://www.google.de/&amp;sig=K_DtcF1dnV7Xn6g9Ir_3SUs6a6TiA%3D">',
      url = new DOMParser()
            .parseFromString(str, 'text/html')
            .documentElement.querySelector('a')
            .href;

console.log(url.includes('domain') ? url : null);
```

---

For those who think that parsing the valid anchor tag is too much work for a reliably constructed string, then you can use regex as a shortcut (but I probably wouldn't in a professional application).

Use a literal space (or word boundary - `\b`) before `href` to ensure that you are targetting the correct attribute and not making a partial match on a larger attribute.  I am going to presume that the input string is guaranteed to be wrapped in double quotes, so match the string between the double quotes.  Within the double quotes, match one or more non-double-quote characters (greedily), then the sought word `domain`, then one or more non-double-quote characters (greedily).  This will return the isolated url if it qualifies and weed out a few fringe cases that could damage the result.

```js
let str = `<a class="domain" data-dummy-href="example.com" href="https://www.google.com/setprefdomain?prefdom=DE&amp;prev=https://www.google.de/&amp;sig=K_DtcF1dnV7Xn6g9Ir_3SUs6a6TiA%3D" style="background-image: url('http://www.example.com/domain/123.png')">`;

console.log(str.match(/ href="([^"]+domain[^"]+)"/i)[1] || 'Not valid');
```

If `domain` may occur at the start or at the end of the href value, then respectively change `+` to `*` to change the qualifier from "one or more" to "zero or more".

Answer (score 0):

I think [@jscrip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71563162/15048478) may be the most straight forward way.  Alternatively, you could check to see if the string [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) the string 'domain' before matching the regex.  For example:

```js
let str = '<a href="https://www.google.com/setprefdomain?prefdom=DE&amp;prev=https://www.google.de/&amp;sig=K_DtcF1dnV7Xn6g9Ir_3SUs6a6TiA%3D">'

let href = str.includes('domain') ? str.match(/(?<=href=").*(?=")/)[0] : 'Not valid'

console.log(href)
```

Comment: Now try your pattern against `<a href="https://www.google.com/setprefdomain?a=b" class="highlight" data-special="yes">`  Your pattern may work for the sample, but cannot be relied upon for general use.  Greedy quantifiers are efficient, but can lead to overmatching if the subpattern is not sufficiently narrowed.

Comment: Furthermore, using two lookarounds on each step that the regex engine takes will not be efficient.